# SharedPreferences not working in Android Java file

Tags: java, android

I am an Android beginner and I git cloned a project https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject where I was learning by doing experiments.

**I simply want to save the country value in SharedPreference whenever the Country is selected from the Picker.**

But there was an issue that I came across while learning is, that I am unable to store the SharedPreferences in this project.

I tried searching all possible methods, but it's simply not working.
Here is one of the samples i tried:

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Also I tried

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
```

And similarly, tried many codes to get it to work.
But the only issue coming in above 2 codes is - **Cannot find symbol method getActivity()**

Please  help.

**Edit:**

I have also tried putting **this** instead of **getActivity()** and also tried **getApplicationContext()** in place of **this** but nothing worked.
I am actually working in a java file named **CountryCodePicker.java** which extends **public class CountryCodePicker extends RelativeLayout {**

Here is the piece of sample code:
i.imgur.com/tzvtXMC.png and i have written in file - https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject/blob/master/ccp/src/main/java/com/hbb20/CountryCodePicker.java

I have also tried adding the code in MainActivity.java file after creating a new method:
i.imgur.com/2FWez9b.png

**Again, I simply want to save the country value in SharedPreference whenever the Country is selected from the Picker.**

Comment: remove `getActivity()`.. just use `this`.because.`getActivity()` is used in fragment class where you needed the Activity's reference

Comment: I have tried this as well.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, those lines of code were in a fragment, and `Fragment` has a `getActivity()` method.

The parameters where you are passing in `getActivity()` need to be replaced with some other sort of `Context`. For example, if you pasted these lines into an activity, you would replace `getActivity()` with `this`.

Comment: @jivvy: If these lines are in `CountryCodePicker`, then use `getContext()` instead of `getActivity()`.

Answer (score 1):

I went through that link. I saw that it uses fragments. But I didn't see where he used Sharedpreferences! Now if you are the one who want to add that functionality to your app, you have to tell us in what class you are using the Sharedpreferences: is it an activity, a fragment, a simple class, an adapter!!!; precision is important for us to help you.

Comment: **I simply want to save the country value in SharedPreference whenever the Country is selected from the Picker in file https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject/blob/master/ccp/src/main/java/com/hbb20/CountryCodePicker.java.**

Answer (score 0):

Also the goad approach is to define SharedPreferences in the App file and to provide Singletone. Thus, you will be available to use that anywhere you want.

Comment: Please focus on the original question. Your post leaves more questions than it answers. What `app file`? What `singleton`? Where's some example code?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `getActivity()` with the context of the application. It can be `this` or `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: Can you plz share your piece of code so the it gets clearer.

Comment: Plz share the complete code of the method in which you are using this.

Comment: You need to make sure that the code you are using is in the activity or fragment class.

Comment: https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject/blob/master/ccp/src/main/java/com/hbb20/CountryCodePicker.java

Comment: I have also tried this in mainactivity file but not working -
 http://i.imgur.com/2FWez9b.png

Comment: In main activity you are using it in a wrong way. Use it like this 'SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); '

Comment: or you can use   `SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);`

Answer (score 0):

if you are working on custom layout (**extends** **RelativeLayout**) first create a **Context** (Context context) instance variable and assign the variable in constructor . then you can call context **getSharedPreferences**.

```
class CountryCodePicker {

    Context context;

    public CountryCodePicker(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public CountryCodePicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;

    }

    public CountryCodePicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.context = context;

    }

    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("pref", 0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is exactly not working? The call to sharedpreferences, the storing of preferences or the retrieval?

As I can see, you are not using its `Editor`

Comment: I asked you to say, I'm what type of class are you using it? An activity, a fragment, an adapter or just any class?

Comment: Imagine, you are saying nothing is working! A programmer cannot say that! It means nothing! Debug it, put breakpoints so that you locate precisely at what position the sharedpreferences is failing.